# ¿El objeto que guarda la instancia de cada clase puede llamarse igual o debe cambiar?

Tags: python-3.x

hola no pongo el codigo porque hace un momento lo puse.¿si creo(hago) una clase que herede de otra clase que contiene un metodo.¿al instanciar la segunda clase debo de cambiarle el nombre o dejo el nombre de la primera instancia?

```
class local1:
def __init__(self,suba):
    self.ASperdidos = 0
    self.suba = suba


def solucion(self):
    i = 0
    #the value is repeated depending on the parameter suba
    while i < self.suba:
        localidad = input("digite su localidad :")
        nota = float(input("digite su nota :"))

        if localidad == "suba" and nota <3.0:
            self.ASperdidos+=1
            i+=1
        else:
            i+=1
        #end the loop
        if i == self.suba:
            print(f"{self.ASperdidos} estudiantes perdieron en {localidad}")

class local2(local1):
    pass


instancia = local1(2)
instancia.solucion()

instancia2 = local2(1)
instancia2.solucion()
```

Comment: Deberías colocar código, no buscaré en tus otras preguntas

Comment: ok no se si era hay

Comment: ¿Tu duda es si al objeto que guarda la instancia, de cada clase puede llamarse igual o debe cambiar?

Comment: Si tu duda es si puedes o no hacer `instancia = local1(2)`, `instancia = local2(1)`, por supuesto que puedes, en Python las variables no son más que nombres asociados a una referencia  puedes reasignar tantas veces como quieras al objeto que quieras. Lo que debes plantearte es si necesitas usar el objeto de `local1` después de instanciar `local2v, porque al reasignar a `instancia` el objeto de `local2`el objeto de `local1` es ya inaccesible porque no tiene variable asociada a el, es más, se queda sin referencias y el GC lo eliminará inmediatamente de memoria.

Comment: si esa es mi duda. ¿Tu duda es si al objeto que guarda la instancia, de cada clase puede llamarse igual o debe cambiar? – Aprendiz hace 12 horas